# Bootstrap modal popup not showing in android web view

Tags: html, android-webview, bootstrap-modal

I am using my html page in android view, opening the bootstrap modal on click of button, the same page is working fine in browser but not working it in web view.

Comment: same issue i am getting . not found any solution yet